# ARM Static library links differently with gcc ld and armlink

Tags: gcc, garbage-collection, arm, static-libraries, keil

I've built a static library using arm-none-eabi-gcc and used the -fdata-sections, -ffunction-sections, and --gc-sections to reduce the library memory footprint.

I've used that library successfully within an application sample when building with arm-none-eabi-gcc, but when I try to build the same application with armcc (Keil), I'm getting lots of undefined symbols in the static library.

When I remove the --gc-sections and build using arg-none-eabi-gcc I can see the same undefined symbols as on Keil, I assume --gc-sections got rid of them. But if I add to Keil the --split_sections and --remove options, Keil is still complaining about the undefined symbols.

So three questions:

1- Why the same static libray can be linked with gcc ld and not with armlink?

2- Isn't --gc-sections supposed not to remove undefined symbols as in the ld manual?

3- If I resolve all the undefined symbols by adding the necessary files, will that have considerable impact on library size or will I have only simple references added?

Keil:
Compiler options:

--c99 -c --cpu Cortex-M4.fp -g -O0 --apcs=interwork --split_sections -I.\inc -I.\STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0\Libraries\CMSIS\Include -I.\STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0\Libraries\CMSIS\ST\STM32F4xx\Include -I.\STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0\Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\inc --littleend --fp16_format=none --thumb --wchar32 -I C:\Keil_v5\ARM\RV31\INC -I C:\Keil_v5\ARM\PACK\ARM\CMSIS\3.20.4\CMSIS\Include
-I C:\Keil_v5\ARM\PACK\Keil\STM32F4xx_DFP\1.0.6\Device\Include -DSTM32F40_41xxx -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -D_INT_MIC_ -DSTM32F4XX -o "*.o" --depend "*.d"

Linker Options

--cpu Cortex-M4.fp *.o
--strict --scatter "test.sct"
--cpu=Cortex-M4 --verbose --remove --summary_stderr --info summarysizes --map --xref --callgraph --symbols
--info sizes --info totals --info unused --info veneers
--list ".\test.map"
-o test.axf

Example of errors:

Build target 'test'
linking...
.\test.axf: Warning: L6413W: Disabling merging for mon_target.o(.rodata.str1.4), Section contains misaligned string(s).
.\test.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol exit (referred from main.o).
.\test.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol gen (referred from main.o).
.\test.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol wonder_clear (referred from callmain.o)

Comment: Maybe you should give us the commands and also the error messages.

Comment: Maybe the undefined symbols are in the code that *gnu ld* removed? `--gc-sections` will remove unused functions.  If those unused functions have a symbol that are not defined, then everything you describe fits; except `--gc-section` doesn't remove *undefined symbols*, it removes unused code/data.

Comment: Yes that answers question 2, but still can't get why Keil is behaving differently even if I added split_sections and --remove which are equivalent to gcc options?